# Passing hashes instead of method parameters

Tags: ruby, oop, coding-style

I see that in Ruby (and dynamically typed languages, in general) a very common practice is to pass a hash, instead of declaring concrete method parameters. For example, instead of declaring a method with parameters and calling it like this:

```
def my_method(width, height, show_border)
my_method(400, 50, false)
```

you can do it this way:

```
def my_method(options)
my_method({"width" => 400, "height" => 50, "show_border" => false})
```

I'd like to know your opinion about it. Is it a good or a bad practice, should we do it or not? In what situation using this practice is valid, and it what situation can it be dangerous?

Comment: A little note: `{width => 400, height => 50, show_border => false}` is not valid ruby syntax. I think you mean `{:width => 400, :height => 50, :show_border => false}` or `{width: 400, height: 50, show_border: false}` (the latter is only valid in ruby 1.9.1)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Both approaches have their own advantages and disadvantages, when you use an options hash replacing standard arguments you lose clarity in the code defining the method but gain clarity whenever you use the method because of the pseudo-named paramaters created by using an options hash.

My general rule is if you either have a lot of arguments for a method (more than 3 or 4) or lots of optional arguments then use an options hash otherwise use standard arguments. However when using an options hash it is important to always include a comment with the method definition describing the possible arguments.

Comment: Now, if I were to have an options hash, could I just put the whole hash in, or do I have to pass the keys => values individually?

Comment: It is true that both have advantages and disadvantages, however I disagree with general rule. I believe options are in general bad practice and should be used only if that is the only way to solve a problem.

Answer (score 46):

Ruby has implicit hash parameters, so you could also write

```
def my_method(options = {}) 

my_method(:width => 400, :height => 50, :show_border => false)
```

and with Ruby 1.9 and new hash syntax it can be

```
my_method( width: 400, height: 50, show_border: false )
```

When a function takes more than 3-4 parameters, it's much easier to see which is what, without counting the respective positions.

Comment: As of Ruby 2.7 now, *implicit* hash parameters are deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.0 – means, we need again the `{…}` *explicitly* to pass a hash ([see](https://bloggie.io/@kinopyo/how-to-fix-ruby-2-7-warning-using-the-last-argument-as-keyword-parameters-is-deprecated)). The Ruby 1.9 syntax shown here is still possible for calling a method with *keyword* parameters.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that if you are either:

1. Having more than 6 method parameters
2. Passing *options* that have some required, some optional and some with default values

You would most probably want to use a hash. It's much easier to see what the arguments mean without looking up in the documentation.

To those of you saying it's hard to figure what options a method takes, that just means that the code is poorly documented. With [YARD](http://yardoc.org), you can use the `@option` tag to specify options:

```
##
# Create a box.
#
# @param [Hash] options The options hash.
# @option options [Numeric] :width The width of the box.
# @option options [Numeric] :height The height of the box.
# @option options [Boolean] :show_border (false) Whether to show a
#   border or not.
def create_box(options={})
  options[:show_border] ||= false
end
```

But in that specific example there's such few and simple parameters, so I think I'd go with this:

```
##
# Create a box.
#
# @param [Numeric] width The width of the box.
# @param [Numeric] height The height of the box.
# @param [Boolean] show_border Whether to show a border or not.
def create_box(width, height, show_border=false)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

**It is not common practice in Ruby to use a hash rather than formal parameters.**

I think *this is being confused* with the common pattern of passing a hash as a parameter when the parameter can take a number of values e.g. setting attributes of a Window in a GUI toolkit.

If you have a number of arguments to your method or function then explicitly declare them and pass them. You get the benefit that the interpreter will check that you have passed all the arguments.

Don't abuse the language feature, know when to use it and when not to use it.

Comment: If you need variable number of arguments just use `def method(*args)`, hashes don't solve that particular problem

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the potential confusion. I was really thinking of the case the original poster raised where the order and number of parameters is variable.

Comment: To add to that point, that anti-pattern is also known as [Magic Container](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicContainer)

Answer (score 3):

I think this method of parameter passing is much clearer when there are more than a couple of parameters or when there are a number of optional parameters. It essentially makes method calls manifestly self-documenting.

Answer (score 3):

The benefit of using an `Hash` as parameter is that you remove the dependency on the number and order of arguments.

In practice this means that you'll later have the flexibility to refactor/change your method without breaking the compatibility with the client code (and this is very good when building libraries because you can't actually change the client code).

(Sandy Metz's ["Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby"](http://www.poodr.com/) is a great book if you're interested in software design in Ruby)

Comment: While your statement is true I don't think is the best way to keep a library compatible. You can achieve the same by simply adding new parameters as optional. They do not break compatibility and still have benefit of clarity and self-documentation.

Comment: @DraganNikolic I'm on board with  the sany metz stuff too - the benefits of not having to arrange a list of manual parameters is huge & there's other ways of self-documenting code laid out in the book

Comment: Another thing many (included me!) often forget is that the order of parameters is a dependency too!

This mean that just use optional params means you can't change the order of params for whatever reason (but usually you don't want many args arguments anyway!)

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice. You don't need to think about method signature and the order of the arguments. Another advantage is that you can easily omit the arguments you do not want to enter.
You can take a look at the ExtJS framework as it is using this type of argument passing extensively.

Answer (score 1):

It's a trade-off. You lose some clarity (how do I know what params to pass) and checking (did I pass the right number of arguments?) and gain flexibility (the method can default params it doesn't receive, we can deploy a new version that takes more params and break no existing code)

You can see this question as part of the larger Strong/Weak type discussion. See [Steve yegge's](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/is-weak-typing-strong-enough) blog here. I've used this style in C and C++ in cases where I wanted to support quite flexible argument passing. Arguably a standard HTTP GET, with some query parameters is exactly this style.

If you go for the hash appraoch I'd say that you need to make sure your testing is really good, problems with incorrectly spelled parameter names will only show up at run time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure no one using dynamic languages cares, but think about the performance penalty your program is going to be hit with when you start passing hashes to functions.

The interpreter may *possibly* be smart enough to create a static const hash object and only reference it by pointer, if the code is using a hash with all members that are source code literals.

But if any of those members are variables then the hash must be reconstructed each time it is called.

I've done some Perl optimizations and this kind of thing can become noticeable in inner code loops.

Function parameters perform much better.

Answer (score 1):

In general we should always use standard arguments, unless it's not possible. Using options when you do not have to use them is bad practice. Standard arguments are clear and self-documented (if properly named).

One (and maybe the only) reason to use options is if function receives arguments which does not process but just pass to another function.

Here is an example, that illustrates that:

```
def myfactory(otype, *args)
  if otype == "obj1"
    myobj1(*args)
  elsif otype == "obj2"
    myobj2(*args)
  else
    puts("unknown object")
  end
end

def myobj1(arg11)
  puts("this is myobj1 #{arg11}")
end

def myobj2(arg21, arg22)
  puts("this is myobj2 #{arg21} #{arg22}")
end
```

In this case 'myfactory' is not even aware of the arguments required by the 'myobj1' or 'myobj2'. 'myfactory' just passes the arguments to the 'myobj1' and 'myobj2' and it's their responsibility to check and process them.

Answer (score 1):

Hashes are particularly useful to pass multiple optional arguments. I use hash, for example to initialize a class whose arguments are optional.

## EXAMPLE

```
class Example

def initialize(args = {})

  @code

  code = args[:code] # No error but you have no control of the variable initialization. the default value is supplied by Hash

  @code = args.fetch(:code) # returns IndexError exception if the argument wasn't passed. And the program stops

  # Handling the execption

  begin

     @code = args.fetch(:code)

  rescue 

 @code = 0

  end

end
```