# Should I use keyword arguments for a method with just a single argument?

Tags: ruby

If I have a method that takes just a single argument, should I use keyword arguments?

```
def say(text = '')
  puts text
end

say('Doh!')
Doh!
```

or

```
def say(text: '')
  puts text
end

say(text: 'Doh!')
Doh!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927291/passing-hashes-instead-of-method-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of them, its entirely your decision. Keyword argument is mostly syntax sugar. It increases code readability and can be preferred depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one argument, than I will recommend to go with single argument.

Keyword arguments makes more sense when you have multiple arguments to be passed, you want it to be synthetically sweet, and no restriction on order or number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There are few advantages of keyword arguments:

1. By using keyword arguments, we know what the arguments mean without
   looking up the implementation of the called method, Keyword
2. arguments allow us to switch the order of the arguments, without
   affecting the behavior of the method

But, if your method is accepting only single argument and method name explanatory enough then its fine to use positional arguments.